# Determine holes in a plane

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, plane

I have a collection of points x and h where h represent holes in a plane. I need to determine the boundary of each hole (as a collection of points). What is the best way to do this? It appears simple but I am struggling to work out an efficient method.

```
x x x x x x x x x x x x x 
x h h h h x x x x x x x x 
x h h h x x x x x x x x x 
X h h x x x h h x x x h h
x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

To be clear - I need the points 'h' that represent the boundary of each collection of 'h' and exclude any interior 'h'.

**EDIT (context):**

I am developing a game which is constructed of many chunks like the above. For each chunk I need to determine the points representing holes in the plane so I can build a collider for the bottom of each hole. I am doing this in C# and Unity3D.

**EDIT 2:**

Edges are not considered boundary points so a hole next to an edge would need to be a non-closed polygon i.e. a line segment.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can iterate through the columns then iterate through the rows. However to find most efficient method I think you need to give more information about your application. For example which environment you are going to use it on.

Comment: show what kind of the result do you expect here

Answer (score 1):

I think algorithm that you're looking for lays in Image Processing area.
Try looking for different algorithm for contour findings.
Here is something to start with:
http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this to find the boundaries of discrete patches of jungle in Costa Rico a lot of years ago.

You've got two problems, one is separating the h's from one hole from the h's from the other holes. The second is working out if they're on the outside or not.

Second problem first, if an 'h' has a neighbour that is an 'x', it's on the outside.

First problem, I solved it kind of like a flood fill. Raster over the array, if it's an 'x' continue. If it's an 'h', label it 1, then find all it's neighbours that are 'h' and label them '1' as well. You can do it recursively.

```
Label(Point p, List<Point> points)
{
  if(map[p]=='h' && !points.Contain(p))
  {
    points.Add(p);
    foreach neighbour of p
       Label(neighbour, points);
  }    
}
```

No promises that it's perfect, but I hope you see where I'm going.
When it's done, points will contain all the contiguous points in the hole.

When that's done, keep going with the raster but label the next 'h' as '2'. When it's finished, you'll have

```
x x x x x x x x x x x x x 
x 1 1 1 1 x x x x x x x x 
x 1 1 1 x x x x x x x x x 
X 1 1 x x x 2 2 x x x 3 3
x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

When that's done go over the points again and any that aren't 'x' and have no 'x' neighbours are inside a hole.

As for efficiency, I did it in C# and it did all of Costa Rica in about 3 ms.

I actually like the Moore-Neighbor Tracing algorithm Eugene posted a link to better than this. When I did this originally I needed all the inside points as well, and I just tacked a "throw away the inside bits" on the end for this problem. Far more elegant to just walk around the outside, as long as you have a simple idea of what neighbour means.

Comment: I guess what I'm not sure about is when I'm looping over the array, how do I make sure I don't select an 'h' that I have already re-cursed over.. If that makes sense?

Comment: you need to keep track of the h points you have visited so you don't visit them twice. you can use another array for this.

Comment: @Adrian Good point, otherwise it won't terminate, but you can use the list you already have.

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition, a point is a boundary point of a region of h's if and only if

1. itself is h and
2. at least one of its neighbours is x.

Hence iterate through all points, consider only the h's and drop all of them which are surrounded by h's only.

You do not define whether h's at the boundary of the entire area are to be considered boundary points of h regions.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. How does this solution deal with multiple holes in the same region? Wouldn't this lump all holes together?